# Send images using sockets Python

Tags: python, image, sockets

I have some problems with this code... send not the integer image but some bytes, is there someone than can help me? I want to send all images I find in a folder. Thank you.

## CLIENT

```
import socket
import sys
import os

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost",9999))       #IP address, port
sb = 'c:\\python27\\invia'

os.chdir(sb)                        #path

dirs =os.listdir(sb)                #list of file
print dirs

for file in dirs:
   f=open(file, "rb")               #read image
   l = f.read()
   s.send(file)                     #send the name of the file
   st = os.stat(sb+'\\'+file).st_size  
   print str(st)
   s.send(str(st))                  #send the size of the file
   s.send(l)                        #send data of the file
   f.close()
s.close()
```

## SERVER

```
import socket
import sys
import os

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",9999))
s.listen(4)                             #number of people than can connect it
sc, address = s.accept()

print address
sb = 'c:\\python27\\ricevi'

os.chdir(sb)
while True:
    fln=sc.recv(5)                      #read the name of the file
    print fln
    f = open(fln,'wb')                  #create the new file
    size = sc.recv(7)                   #receive the size of the file
    #size=size[:7]
    print size
    strng = sc.recv(int(size))          #receive the data of the file 
    #if strng:
    f.write(strng)                      #write the file
    f.close()
sc.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: So what's the problem and what's the question?

Comment: how can send and receive the real bytes of the image?..Because I want to copy the image in an other folder, but the function os.stat or os.getsize don't work so good. The code is very simple but I don't understand why it doesn't work accurately

Comment: So, have you tried Googling for “Python socket send file”?

Comment: do you get any errors or anything which tells us what your actuall problem is ?

Answer (score 1):

To transfer a sequence of files over a single socket, you need some way of delineating each file.  In effect, you need to run a small protocol on top of the socket which allows to you know the metadata for each file such as its size and name, and of course the image data.

It appears you're attempting to do this, however both sender and receiver must agree on a protocol.

You have the following in your sender:

```
s.send(file)                     #send the name of the file
st = os.stat(sb+'\\'+file).st_size  
s.send(str(st))                  #send the size of the file
s.send(l)
```

How is the receiver to know how long the file name is?  Or, how will the receiver know where the end of the file name is, and where the size of the file starts?  You could imagine the receiver obtaining a string like `foobar.txt8somedata` and having to infer that the name of the file is `foobar.txt`, the file is 8 bytes long containing the data `somedata`.

What you need to do is separate the data with some kind of delimeter such as `\n` to indicate the boundary for each piece of metadata.

You could envisage a packet structure as `<filename>\n<file_size>\n<file_contents>`.  An example stream of data from the transmitter may then look like this:

```
foobar.txt\n8\nsomedata
```

The receiver would then decode the incoming stream, looking for `\n` in the input to determine each field's value such as the file name and size.

Another approach would be to allocate fixed length strings for the file name and size, followed by the file's data.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to [`socket.recv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket#socket.socket.recv) only specifies the maximum buffer size for receiving data packages, it doesn't mean exactly that many bytes will be read.

So if you write:

```
strng = sc.recv(int(size))
```

you won't necessarily get all the content, specially if `size` is rather large.

You need to read from the socket in a loop until you have actually read `size` bytes to make it work.

Comment: sorry, how can I do a loop?

Comment: in your case you could do something like [this](http://pastebin.com/nemRgcpy). Or use `socket.makefile` to convert it to a filelike object, which's read method would block until EOF. Also, your way of sending only works if the length of the filename is exactly 5 and the filesize has 7 digits...